# Creating a "formation" from a range of any numbers

Tags: python

I would like to create a 'formation' for my boids to follow but there can be any number of boids in the formation. I would like a circle formation. So how can I go through the number of boids in the formation and manipulate there (x,y) so that they fill out a circular shape?

I have:`self.flock_formation = [] under class Flock.__init__ and self.pos(math3d.VectorN(x,y) under class Boid.__init__`

This is in class Flock:

```
def create_formation(self):
    for boid in range(0, len(self.boids)):
        spot = math3d.VectorN(x, y)
        self.flock_formation.append(spot)
```

I am having trouble understanding what I might need to do to come up with the positions in a circle the size of the number of boids in the flock. Any ideas or example code would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to choose a radius for your circle.  Here is one algorithm to do it.

```
import math

for pos in range(len(self.boids)):
    angle = 2*math.pi / n
    x = radius * math.sin(angle)
    y = radius * math.cos(angle)
```

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes I think so, could I say radius is the length of the number of boids?

Comment: This is entirely up to your design.  You didn't specify anything in your question.  This is simply the radius of the circle.  What spacing requirements do you have?

Comment: Actually this works, I forgot the use of sin and cosine. This only works in 2D but I think I can work this into Vector math.

Comment: You asked for a circle; that's a 2D figure.  Did you actually want an N-sphere (where N is the dimension of your vector)?  That's a more complex problem, generally involving multi-D partitions and sections of Euclidean N-solids (the boids go at the vertices).